# Switching Partitions

Tags: sql, switch-statement

Is it possible to switch more than one partition at once with one query?

I have 700 partitions in a table that I want to switch to its corresponding table with one query.
I tried writing this query

```
DECLARE @num INT = 1

WHILE @num <= 700

BEGIN

ALTER TABLE SourceTable

SWITCH TO DestinationTable PARTITION @num  
SET @num = @num +1

END
```

Comment: "switch partitions" ?? It is unclear what you are trying to do. Because, in my opinion, selecting from a partitioned table will let MySQL decide which partitions are needed to access to retrieve the data (and you should not need to check them yourself)

Comment: There is no such feature in MySQL. You may restrict SELECT with definite partitions only (or it can be performed automatically if possible - see partition pruning).

Comment: *`DECLARE @num INT = 1`* This is not legal in MySQL. Check your DBMS carefully... Maybe you use MS SQL (SQL Server)?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?